# Two semantic interpretaions for 'I've ever seen'

Tags: complements, relative-clauses

> The slim thighs **I’ve ever seen**. (1)
>  The slimmest thighs **I’ve ever
>   seen**. (2)

Grammatically, the first highlighted part might be called relative clause modifying the previous noun phrase, and the second, complement for the previous phrase –– the latter explanation is seen in [CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/):"indirect complement, complement licensed by the comparative inflection (p.547)". What I want to know is what different meaning you get from the same appearance –– I’ve ever seen.

Comment: @snailboat, the first example I've changed from 'the slim thighs I've always imagined'(Water for Elephants). I have thought the first has the same meaning with 'the slim thighs I've always seen'.

Comment: @snailboat, then can I present this - “Do you want to see the slim thighs I’ve ever seen?” instead of (1)? If it's possible, I want to change both (1) and (2) into interrogatives.

Comment: Not thinking fast enough for an analytic explanation why, but **I've ever seen** always accompanies a superlative. The **ever** is indicating an extremum of some characteristic, so you need to be discussing some suitable extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ever* is an interesting word. From its earliest appearances, about the year 1000, it bore two related senses:

1. At **all** times, in **all** cases, on **all** occasions
2. At **any** time, in **any** case, on **any** occasion

The **all** sense, however, began to wane after the 17th century. It continued in literary use into the early 20th century, and it survives in such combinations as  *evergreen, ever-changing, forever and ever*. But that sense is no longer 'productive' of new combinations, except when a user wants to create an archaic or 'elevated' feel. (However, the sense *does* survive indirectly in *every*, an adjectival form which derives from an Old English form equivalent to *ever each*.)

Today only the **any** sense is used in ordinary discourse.

So a good test for acceptability of *ever* is to substitute the phrase *at any time*. This one is fine:

> <sup>OK</sup>Those are the slimmest thighs I have seen *at any time*.

But this one doesn't make any sense:

> <sup>∗</sup>Those are the slim thighs I have seen *at any time*.

It does work, however, in questions, negations and conditions:

> <sup>OK</sup>Have you *at any time* noticed those slim thighs?
>   <sup>OK</sup>I have not *at any time* noticed those slim thighs.
>   <sup>OK</sup>If I had *at any time* noticed those slim thighs I have forgotten them.